# Ready function in a new window

Tags: javascript

Sorry I am completly new and was not sure how to write this question.
Basically when I open a new window with `window.open` I need the new window to do something.
I cannot use window.location.href because its a different url each time.

I want it to do this

```
var mywindow = window.open(url);
myWindow.ready function(){
//do stuff
}
```

I just can't seam to find the right thing to make this work. any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `mywindow.onload = function () {...};` is probably what you need.

Comment: What are you expecting "ready" to do?

Answer (score 1):

To execute some action when page is loading you have some ways like:

```
window.onload = function() {

};
```

Comment: In this case, just use window.onload: